# How do I remove rows by name that don't appear in a list in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm very new to coding, so perhaps there is a super simple answer for this, but here it goes:

I have a dataframe of a bunch of stocks. Each stock has a ticker and their names are stored in a column. I've created a list of all the stocks I want in my data frame. I am wondering how I remove the stocks with tickers that do not appear in my list.

```
from pandas import *
C = DataFrame(["TD","CM","AAPL","GOOG", "GOOS"],columns=["Ticker"])
```

There are several hundred occurrences of each ticker, and each has an associated price, return, risk free rate, and time. I've created a list of stocks that I want to analyze, based on how many occurrences they have in the dataframe. I have already done this, but the simplified list looks like this:

```
list = ['GOOG', 'AAPL']
```

I want to return a dataframe that only has these tickers in it, but also includes all the row data associated with each one. I'm honestly pretty stumped on how to do this, but I'm sure there is a simple answer. Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this.

```
tickers = ['GOOG', 'AAPL']
df = C.loc[C['Ticker'].isin(tickers)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

---

```
#df
  Ticker
0   AAPL
1   GOOG
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.